# What does the new "Execution hints" button do?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-script-editor

I've just noticed a new button in the toolbar of the Google Apps Script IDE. It looks like a lightbulb, and the alt text on it says "Execution hints". I can't find anything in Support, Release Notes, or the Blog about this button.

Does anybody know what it does? I can't seem to make the button active to try it out.

[image: Location of new button]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The button seems to only be enabled if you have something in your code which they have pre-defined hints for.

For example: I finally saw the button enabled when I was working on one of my custom spreadsheet functions. When clicked, this popped up over my code:

[image]

I, too, was intrigued by this new button when it first appeared a few days ago, and I was surprised to see nothing about it in the official [Google Apps Script Release Notes](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/releases/).

Once I figured out what it does, I came here to see if anyone else had asked about it.

@mwjeffcott Update: Another one of my projects actually had some helpul "execution hints." It told me about deprecated functions that I was using. I mean, it *could* have been more helpful by providing the sunset date and the recommended "alternative solution," but it's better than nothing I guess.

[image]

Comment: Too bad it appeared to you to criticize you code XD - but thanks for the tip, it was indeed intriguing...

Comment: Haha yeah. Also worth noting: It criticized that I use getValue() heavily in one of my scripts (the button is enabled throughout the entire project in the script editor, but only refers to specific script files), but I only use getValue() once in that script file. It _is_ in a for loop which loops about 200 times, but the editor has no idea how many times this for loop is going to run during execution. So I tried commenting out the for loop, but the "hint" still remained. Weird.

Comment: FYI, I provide more details in this G+ post.